# iOS: Simulator location in XCUITest not working

Tags: ios, location, xctest, simulator, xcuitest

The only way to get the simulator to spit back a location is by changing the location in the simulator itself. When I change the settings in the scheme it doesn't seem to do anything.

Am I missing something?

Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should be the answer:

https://willowtreeapps.com/ideas/simulating-location-in-ios

Setting it in XCode only won't work, you have to check and set your Simulator->Debug->Location correctly as well.

Comment: Thanks for responding. The issue with that is that I'm trying to run tests within a CI environment; so I'm not accessing the Simulator instances beforehand. That's why I was hoping I could set it in Xcode and that would take care of kicking off the simulators with the right settings.

Comment: Well you haven't said that :-) I will look into our CI settings and let you know, I am sure that you can set location with XCode line tools and do it in CI

Answer (score 0):

Oky, after extensive testing on our repo - this is, what you are looking for:

https://github.com/JonGabilondoAngulo/idevicelocation

You can use it from console (from CI) to set location to your simulator and it works like a charm :-)